# RewriteRule returning a different result between server side and localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

What am I doing wrong? Why will the following open the file test.php 
which is in my main dir correctly on the server side but not on my localhost?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(contact)$ /test\.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

As result on the server side I get the following page displayed: `example.com/contact`
On localhost, this is opening a kind of Wamp server tree, since I'm using Wamp. Other redirections are working well e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index\.php [QSA,L]
```

Does someone know what is causing this to happen?

Comment: I'm not a native-born English speaker so I'm not sure if I understand what foo & bar mean since English speakers use this in computing...If you meant: RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /test\.php?view=$1 [L,R]  than the localhost is returning: http://localhost/test.php?view=  when I enter localhost/sitename/contact - The problem is only with localhost

Comment: Change your rule to this: `RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ test.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]` and retest

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much. When is the question-mark to be put on the left side. What does it indicate in this case? I like understanding what I'm doing, hope it is not too much asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
 RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ test.php?view=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

and retest.

This will rewrite `contact` to `test.php` in same directory where your .htaccess is kept. Your rule is rewriting same request to `test.php` on site root due to leading `/` in target URI.

`/?$` on pattern makes trailing slash optional in request URI.

Comment: Fine! I've just learnt something more about the /? Have a nice day and thank you again.